# Installing and Using Pantomime Framework... Pantomime/Pantomime.h not found

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I just downloaded and compiled Pantomime for SMTP use in my Cocoa Application.  The first issue was that it is old... so I changed the build settings to use the most recent SDK as well as eliminate the old PPC build settings.

After those changes, everything compiled nicely (or at least appeared to do so.)

Next, I installed the Pantomime.framework into the /Library/Frameworks directory per Apple documentation recommendations.

Then, I imported the framework into my project under the Build Phases tab where it says "Link Binaries to Libraries".

So far everything seemed to work as it did with WebKit.framework, and ScriptingBridge.framework.

Finally, I added the following to my code:

```
#import <Pantomime/Pantomime.h>
```

I got as far as "Pa" when it auto completed the rest, so it apparently knows what I'm looking for.  However, when I try to compile my code, I receive the following error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue "Pantomime/Pantomime.h" file not found.
```

All of the other frameworks seemed to work, but this one does not, and I really don't know why (I'm relatively new to working with frameworks.)

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Pantomime, but this happens to me all the time with Xcode, so although I'm a newbie to development in general I'd wager it's just a bug with Xcode. Here's how I fix it:

In Xcode, hit command-1 to switch to the Navigator's file/folder view.

Reveal the Pantomime.h and .m files in the Finder, wherever you've stored them.

Drag them into the Navigator.

Xcode will prompt you to confirm adding again, and I usually leave it set as is to "copy files if needed".

Xcode will import. You should then delete the old references in the Navigator. It should work fine after that.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried this 4 times earlier today and it didn't work... however, this time it did.  The only thing that I've done differently this time, was to check the "copy files if needed".  For some reason, it was either off or I had turned it off.  That apparently made all the difference.  I'm wondering if frameworks need to be copied in...

Anyway.. Check for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem.
The solution is setting 'Build Settings' --> 'Header Search Path' Value where your pantomime is. Good luck!